# bootstrap modal - remote url. Can I put the whole modal element into remote.html?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm using bootstrap 2.3.2. According to http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals 
if data-remote url is provided, then the content of the url will be injected into .modal-body.

My index.html:

```
<a data-remote="remote.php" data-target="#myModal" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal Test Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>​
```

remote.php

```
<div>remote content goes here</div>
```

which means  remote content goes here will be inserted into modal-body and replaced

One fine body...

However, I wonder if I can save the whole #myModel into remote.html ie. take out the #myModal from index.html and put it into remote.php. I have tried that but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I have a modal this way...

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $( "#placeholder" ).load( "/html/myExternalModalDiv.html", function() {
            $('#myExternalModalDiv').modal('toggle');
        });
     </script>
<![endif]-->
```

This loads an external modal markup and fire it (just for internet explorer < 9 in my case)
I hope this will be usefull as example.